# Modify filename before saving with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I've an uploader where I've implement the #filename method to get a custom and unique filename but it looks like this method is ignored before saving the file (I'm uploading to rackspace with the fog gem)

Here is the uploader:

```
class MyImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  ...

  def filename
    if original_filename.present?
      "#{secure_token}.#{file.path.split('.').last.downcase}"
    else
      super
    end
  end

  ...

  private

  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end
end
```

And here is a test in the console (I'm testing an issue with large filenames that I thought was solved with the custom #filename method):

```
1.9.3-p392 :002 > f = File.open('/Users/myuser/Desktop/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.png')
 => #<File:/Users/myuser/Desktop/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.png>
1.9.3-p392 :003 > my_model_instance.image = f
Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: File name too long - /Users/myuser/app/tmp/uploads/20130509-1723-16769-8458/thumb_lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat4lolcat.png
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `initialize'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `open'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `block in copy_file'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `open'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `copy_file'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:477:in `copy_file'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:396:in `block in cp'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1515:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1531:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1513:in `fu_each_src_dest'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:395:in `cp'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:205:in `copy_to'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:121:in `block in cache!'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112:in `cache!'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:231:in `block in cache_versions!'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:216:in `each'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:216:in `cache_versions!'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112:in `cache!'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:315:in `cache'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:173:in `image='
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@app/bundler/gems/carrierwave-mongoid-28a9b718d42b/lib/carrierwave/mongoid.rb:39:in `image='
```

So I think that I need to modify the filename before being saved in order to get the custom filename fully working because actually the file only is rename after being uploaded to Rackspace (only if the filename it's not so large)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upload is exploding during the caching step (which happens locally) rather than the saving step (which happens in fog). Reading [the source](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/v0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb), it looks like carrierwave has a method you can override to do just this: full_original_filename

If the problem you're trying to solve is to make the cached filename shorter, the following may work. If you want to change that filename later, you'll need to use the [official solution for that](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files) in addition.

```
MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 64 # arbitrary limit, your milage may vary

def full_original_filename
  filename = super

  return filename if !filename.present?

  extension = File.extname(filename)
  basename = File.basename(filename, extension)[0...MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH]
  basename + extension
end
```

Comment: Hi Taavo, thank you for the help. Your change effectively updates the local filename before reading but it looks like I need to move the file first because I get a "No such file or directory" error which is pointing the the new filename: /Users/myuser/app/tmp/uploads/20130510-1222-59710-2769/4f7dfe24-c39c-4cda-bf99-ed09cea0a162.png

Comment: I've written up an alternate implementation that may work, but I'm suspicious this won't resolve the your issue either. I haven't tested it...

Comment: I am using Carrierwave gem and when i download the file, if that file name contains space then it's converted into underscores. So how to remove that underscore from the filename while downloading it ?